# send and receive data through raw body of a WebRequest using wcf restful service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

i have implemented a WCF RESTful webservice which takes parameters though raw body during `http POST`.when tested over `"POSTMAN"` chrome extension it gives desired results like in the below images:

[image: REST service url and raw body parameters]

Now i want to get the same result while consuming the same service through an ASP web application using below code

```cs
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.19/SSARESTservice/SSA/IMEIVerification");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
DeviceData data = new DeviceData() { IMEI = "352423061590616" };
string str = ser.Serialize(data);
byte[] databyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
request.ContentLength = databyte.Length;
var reqStrm = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStrm.Write(databyte, 0, databyte.Length);

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var respStrm = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStrm);
string bodyprm = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but while executing the above code poses the following error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Line 34: `var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Here is my operation contract

```cs
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "IMEIVerification", Method = "POST",  ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat =       WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)
[OperationContract]
JsonResponseProps VerifyDevice(DeviceData data);
```

And the implementation

```cs
public JsonResponseProps VerifyDevice(DeviceData data)
{
JsonResponseProps jis = new JsonResponseProps();
using (con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("select IMEI from dbo.tbl_master_Devicedata where IMEI='" + data.IMEI + "'", con);
var IMEI = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (IMEI != null)
{
jis.msg = "Verification Successful";
jis.success = "true";
}
else
{
jis.msg = "Verification Failed";
jis.success = "false";
}
con.Close();
}
return jis;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you share the code in the restful service that defines the method call?  Please include all WCF attributes on the interface and the method definition.  Please edit the question to clean up the code block.

Comment: Add trace listener so as to learn more about exception!

Comment: @SOHO Developer   i've been using SO for almost 3 years but never posted a question.feels great to see comments already.i'll edit my question by adding the wcf service code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with POSTMAN you send:

```
{"data":{"IMEI":"352423061590616"}}
```

but when you inspect the serialized data from

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

DeviceData data = new DeviceData() { IMEI = "352423061590616" };

string str = ser.Serialize(data);
```

You'll see that the wireformat is:

```
{"IMEI":"352423061590616"}
```

And that doesn't map well on your `data` argument.

To resolve this add an extra class for the purpose of Root container. It has a data property from the type `DeviceData` to hold your actual payload. The code to serialize would look like this:

```
// container with a data property
// this one is being serialized
public class Root
{
    public DeviceData data { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceData
{
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
}

protected void CallIMEIVerfication()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    DeviceData data = new DeviceData() { IMEI = "352423061590616" };
    var root = new Root { data=data };
    string str = ser.Serialize(root);
    // rest of your code
}
```